# Bootstrap, multi field search bar

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a multi filed search bar for a new website. The website is made in PHP/Javascript/Bootstrap

I need to create 4 fields (3 text field + 1 search button) and they should be aligned in a

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
       ..here the fields plus button...
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that? I tried form-inline but this is the result:

[image]

Comment: `float: left` on the inputs and the button?

Comment: this will force the elements to take all the space? what if I want the button to be shorter?

Comment: That won't make the elements take up all the space, it will make them display in a line.  You can adjust their css `width` property (maybe give the inputs 30% width and the button 10%)

Comment: ok it works. unfortunately the fields don't collapse into four rows when in mobile mode

Comment: If you have a way to detect mobile mode, you can apply `clear: both` to the inputs and the button while mobile.  That will make them wrap down to a new line

Comment: in bootstrap there are visible-xx and hidden-xx class rules which selectively enable / disable div elements depending on the screen size. Probably I need two input groups that toggle on and off

Comment: post the solution as a proper answer and I'll accept it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have particularly problematic requirements like old browser support, you could have fun with Flex.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You have to distribute until 12 cols and center your div like:

Change Your code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
       ..here the fields plus button...
   </div>
</div>
```

For:

```
<!--Adding some styles for center the row-->
<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; display:block; width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-lg-2">Field One</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">Field Two</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">Field Tree</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Your search field</div>
</div>
```

Please see this for: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid more about it.